# Different version of VS2012 requires project migration?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a project that was created using VS2102 Premium.  When a co-worker tries to open it with VS2012 Professional he gets a "Needs migration" message for the project.  Is this due to the different flavor of VS2012?

Comment: Are you both running the same VS 2012 Update?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have thought so for most projects, however if you've used some feature of VS Premium that is not present in VS Professional, then I guess this is the response you'll get.

If you open a project from a previous version (eg 2010) then it'll offer to upgrade the solution.

You can manually edit the project, its only an XML file. Create a new blank project to see the structure and then use winmerge or similar to copy relevant lines across.